# Why write a exists file faster than write a new empty file

Tags: java, linux, file, nio

I use MappedByteBuffer to write file in linux.

```
File file = new File("testFile");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, file.length());
mbf.put(buffer);
```

If testFile has write 500MB, and write the 500MB data twice, it takes 1s.but when I rm testFile, write the 500MB data, it takes 4s.

Why override a file is faster than write a new file?
How can I write a new file as faster as override a file?

Comment: How are you measuring the time it takes?

Comment: the answer most likely depends on the underlaying file system. Therefore it has nothing to do with Java. Ask this question (without pointing to Java) at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you sure it's writing 500MB in the latter case? It should be throwing a `BufferOverflowException` because `file.length()` is 0 when the file is newly created.

Comment: Because the file space is already allocated.